# Saving all Excel workbooks in Outlook attachments to another location

Tags: excel, vba, file-io, outlook

I am working on an excel vba macro which should copy only  excel files from outlook to a different location

I have the following code

```
Sub Test(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
        saveFolder = "C:\APIndex"
    Dim dateFormat As String
        dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

Using the above code I was able to download all files including some images and pdfs but I just want .xls and .xlsx files.

**Is there a good way I can do this?**

Comment: It's not clear how your posted code (saving attachments from an outlook item) relates to your question (copying all Excel files from one folder to another)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I changed the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement some sort of pre-filtering using for example, VBA `InStr()` to check if the file name contain .`xls` or . xlsx, like shown in the following snippet:

```
if (InStr(1, FileName, ".xls") >0 Or InStr(1, FileName, ".xlsx") >0) Then
'Save the File
End If
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks but how do I get the file name from the attachment. noy sure if .DisplayName gives filename with .xls

Comment: Well, it should, otherwise where the saved File Name comes from? Try to get the File Name property and use it in a simple InStr() check. Best regards,